# Limit of $\frac{a^{n+1}(n+1)!^b}{\sum_{k=0}^n a^kk!^b}$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

I want to prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a^{n+1}(n+1)!^b}{\sum_{k=0}^n a^kk!^b}<\infty$$ for $a,b>0$.

This is the last step of a bigger problem. I believe it would suffice to use good enough upper and lower bounds for the factorials, but I don't know such bounds. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further conditions on $a$ and $b$, this cannot be true. For example, let $a=b=1$, and let $n \ge 1$.  Then the numerator is $(n+1)!$. The denominator is $\le n(n-1)!+n!$, that is, $\le 2(n!)$, so the ratio is $\ge (n+1)/2$.

Comment: I originally thought $0 < a < 1$ would suffice, but I think even this is wrong.  If $a = 1/2$, and $b = 1$, then the limit is still $\infty$, for the same reason here (with a slightly modified bound).

Comment: @NicholasStull: Yes, $b=1$ is a problem in any case.

Comment: Here is the link to the question that lead me to this limit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142489/upper-bound-for-the-series-sum-n-geq-1-frac1n1a1-sum-k-0n-bk I am completely suck and any little help would be great!

Comment: I am beginning to wonder if this statement is actually false for $b > 0$, if $b$ is constant (with respect to $n$).  I suspect we must require $b\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.  But even that may not be sufficient.

Comment: @wircho, thanks for the reference to the other problem.  I will look into this, but I suspect it may be possible to prove the limit in this question exists if $b = \frac{1}{n^2}$.